# Optimizing theano - reusing predefined modules as part of computational graph

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I know this has been asked a few years ago but I think my question is a little different (and solutions might have come up).

I'm using theano to train a neural network. My input samples are of different sizes so I'm redefining the entire cost function per input sample, which makes theano very slow (even when using the fast-compile flag, which does improve, but not enough).

As far as theano is concerned, on every new sample I'm defining a completely new function that is derived from scratch. I *am*, however, using the very same building blocks to yield the cost function, as 99% of the cost function is calculated via 
`T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(W,h)+b)`. The difference is which `h` I'm putting there every time.

As far as I know, I can't use `theano.function` to define this as a building block, because I cannot give it as input the symbolic variable `h` (that is, in turn, defined by another such calculation). I also cannot use `theano.scan` because I don't have a stream of data on which I'm repeatedly applying a function.

I do think that something should be able to improve this, because after all, considering the theory of neural networks, my structure here is easily* derivable using the error message passing, but I don't know how I can "tell" theano that I'm actually building my network from the same blocks over and over again.

*Since I'm always changing my network structure, I would want to avoid direct backprop calculations, that's why I'm using theano.

I'd appreciate any assistance on the subject.